# C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#

```
DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
string format = "ddd";
Console.WriteLine(Time.ToString(format));
if (Time = "Mon; Tue; Wed; Thu; Fri;") 

{
    Console.WriteLine("It is a week day");
}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("it is a weekend");
}
```

I'm trying to get this code to check for the date and the display a response based on the day. Sorry if this is a simple question but I'm new to coding and I cant find a solution anywhere

Comment: I agree with Recursive's answer. As a future pointer in C#: if you want to check if a value is in a list, create a list (e.g. var weekdays = new List<string>() { "mon", "tue", ...., }; and then use weekdays.Contains(time) )

Comment: You should really use the DayOfWeek property of DateTime instead of string comparison !

Comment: So so many things wrong with the `if` line :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
bool isWeekDay == DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek > DayOfWeek.Sunday 
    && DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek < DayOfWeek.Saturday;

if (isWeekDay) {
    Console.WriteLine("It is a week day");
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("it is a weekend");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try

```
DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
string format = "ddd";
Console.WriteLine(Time.ToString(format));
string day = Time.ToString(format);
if (day = "Mon; Tue; Wed; Thu; Fri;") 
{
    Console.WriteLine("It is a week day");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("it is a weekend");
}
```